# Reduce gap between section and subsection heading

Tags: sectioning

With the code below, I have a very large space between the section 1 heading and subsection 1.1 heading. I've tried to change the `\titlespacing` options but I still can't reduce this large space.

What adjustments can I make to my code?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{verydarkblue}{HTML}{000052}

\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},
 left=20mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\textcolor{verydarkblue}{\section*{\textbf{\textsc{{section 0}}}}}
\blindtext

\textcolor{verydarkblue}{\section{\textbf{\textsc{{section 1}}}}}
\textcolor{verydarkblue}{\subsection{\textit{subsection 1.1}}}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Don't put explicit markup in the argument to `\section` etc. Put the formatting in your configuration i.e. when you set them up using `titlesec`'s commands. That way, it is easy to keep things both consistent and flexible. You probably need to include some stretch in the spacing you are setting up. See page 5 of `titlesec`'s manual for a way to do this using `*` settings provided by the package.

Comment: `\textcolor{verydarkblue}{\section*{\textbf{\textsc{{section 0}}}}}`You should never have formatting in the argument or around sectioning commands, or number sections "by hand".  In particular if you surround the  heading by a group like this you will mess up the code latex uses for controlling the following paragraph. Just use `\section{title for section zero}` and specify fonts and colours elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the features of `titlesec` for setting color and font of titles.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}% I don't own Calibri

\definecolor{verydarkblue}{HTML}{000052}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{verydarkblue}\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\scshape}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{verydarkblue}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\scshape}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\color{verydarkblue}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section*{section 0}
\blindtext

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't load `xunicode` and `xltxtra`; avoid using `\XeTeXinputencoding` for new documents: save them as UTF-8.

Comment: Excellent, thanks - it is possible to make the heading numbers the same colour as the heading text? I have to use `xunicode`, `xltxtra` and `\XeTexinputencoding` to support foreign characters.

Comment: @user2568648 Move the `\color` command to the second argument of `\titleformat`. I'll fix the code. You *don't* need `xunicode`, `xltxtra` or `\XeTeXinputencoding` for supporting foreign characters. Just be sure to save your file as UTF-8.