# what is the meaning of 0pt 0pt in titlesection

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, paragraphs

I was reading a question here [Reduce gap between section and subsection heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209004/reduce-gap-between-section-and-subsection-heading?rq=1)

I read following `\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`
in the code so I want to know what is meant by 0pt and what effect is produced by using it 3 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step-by-Step Explanation

1. Google `"titlesec ctan"` which will lead you to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec.
2. Search for `"titlespacing"` within the [manual / package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (a PDF document).
3. Then you will find the explanation (see screenshot).

So the command `\titlespacing{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]` has in total 4 mandatory (must have) arguments (`command`, `left`, `before-sep`, and `after-sep`) and one optional argument (`right-sep`).

In your example (`\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`) the `0pt` define the distances/spaces `left`, `before-sep`, and `after-sep`.

[image]

### Hint for (Better) Future Questions

- As of today, you have 16 questions of which 2 questions have only 1 outvote.
- The remaining 14 questions have 0 upvotes or negative upvotes.
- Please consider to improve the quality of your questions and do some basic investigation before you ask a question.
- A good start is to read [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
- I suggest, that you try to understand the point of view of the people who help here in this community.
- I am not an expert - just a long-time user.
- Your question does not show any effort.
- Therefore, please take the time to draft a high-quality question. **Drafting a high-quality question can easily take 1 hour.** The question should clearly explain the problem (for example, input vs. actual output vs. expected output).
- Try to explain what you have tried before.
- The question ideally considers the two links, that I refer to above.
- Another hint is, to use short and clear sentences. In your comments to my answer you have long sentences that are difficult to read and understand.

> **Remark:** Taking the time to "criticize" you is a sign of help and not meant to
>   be negative. This is my free time on the weekend - don't forget that.

Comment: I am not able to undersand the explanation given in the pdf before asking I had seen this pdf I have also saved it on my desktop. In section 2.1 of pdf they mentioned rm sf tt md up bf it sl sc I tried those on my latex (miktex) but they produced verbal output meaning they produced these charachters as it is when I used them.On page 7 in pdf they used same thing pt meaning titlerule[.8pt],I did a `control+f`  pt it gives me 226 results I am on 86th as of now

Comment: @koeradoera I do not understand your comment. Your question asked about the three 0pt in the given command. I show you the meaning of the 0pt by showing you the relevant section in the manual. Your comment seems to address something different.

Comment: actually I am not able to understand after reading the document many times that is what I want to say. I am not able to understand the examples or any thing and I dont have any one to help me to make it understand.So I am not able to ask good questions as you point out.Ideally  I should have been able to sort this out myself and post a question which may be more helpful as you mentioned in your Hint so I have most questions downvoted or closed or like that. I feel I need documentation with some working examples as you type this  then so and so generate this . Following is outout etc etc

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand all this for beginners like me who come from Microsoft Word background of documentation and it looks very very difficult also.

Comment: @koeradoera **(1)** I have updated the answer. **(2)** I suggest, that you try to understand the point of view of the people who help here in this community. I am not an expert - just a long-time user. But your question does not show any effort. Therefore, please take the time to draft a high-quality question. Drafting a high-quality question can easily take 1 hour.

Comment: ok thanks for the update I am now able to understand what is in the pdf and in your answer also.